# Ubuntu 12.04 + Eclipse 64 bits key binding error

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, bind

The text is quite extense so, this is just a part of it:

```
!SESSION 2012-11-23 10:15:52.442 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 10:16:06.408
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 10:16:06.408
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+R:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.rename.command,Rename,
        Rename the selected text.,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.internal.ArtifactRefactoringCommandHandler,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-11-23 10:16:10.409
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.putToolbarLabel(WorkbenchWindow.java:1697)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuAdditionCacheEntry.createToolBarAdditionContribution(MenuAdditionCacheEntry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.MenuAdditionCacheEntry.createContributionItems(MenuAdditionCacheEntry.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3874)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setCoolBarVisible(WorkbenchWindow.java:3675)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewIntroAdapterPart.setBarVisibility(ViewIntroAdapterPart.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewIntroAdapterPart.dispose(ViewIntroAdapterPart.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.doDisposePart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.doDisposePart(ViewReference.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.dispose(WorkbenchPartReference.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.disposePart(WorkbenchPage.java:1801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.partRemoved(WorkbenchPage.java:1793)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewFactory.releaseView(ViewFactory.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.dispose(Perspective.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.dispose(WorkbenchPage.java:1872)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.closeAllPages(WorkbenchWindow.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.hardClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1729)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$0(WorkbenchWindow.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$6.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.WindowManager.close(WindowManager.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$18.run(Workbench.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyClose(Workbench.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$15(Workbench.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$25.run(Workbench.java:1284)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1282)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$0(WorkbenchWindow.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$6.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.handleShellCloseEvent(Window.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window$3.shellClosed(Window.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.closeWidget(Shell.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.gtk_delete_event(Shell.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5116)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4369)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:8295)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1192)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2332)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
!SESSION 2012-11-23 10:36:07.863 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 10:36:13.181
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 10:36:13.181
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+R:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.rename.command,Rename,
        Rename the selected text.,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.internal.ArtifactRefactoringCommandHandler,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-11-23 10:39:04.681
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: CacheManager_CannotLoadNonUrlLocation in: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.messages

!SESSION 2012-11-23 15:14:12.933 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:14:23.380
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:14:23.380
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+R:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.rename.command,Rename,
        Rename the selected text.,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.internal.ArtifactRefactoringCommandHandler,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 4 2 2012-11-23 15:14:32.800
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.internal.uaa.monitor.CommandUsageMonitor.startMonitoring(CommandUsageMonitor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.UaaPlugin$1$1.run(UaaPlugin.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.UaaPlugin$1.run(UaaPlugin.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
!SESSION 2012-11-23 15:15:21.833 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:15:27.283
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:15:27.283
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+R:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.rename.command,Rename,
        Rename the selected text.,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.internal.ArtifactRefactoringCommandHandler,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:18:41.265
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:18:41.265
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+E:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+E,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.rename.command,Rename,
        Rename the selected text.,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.internal.ArtifactRefactoringCommandHandler,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,user)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+E,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,user)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+E,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - JavaScript,JavaScript Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,user)
!SESSION 2012-11-23 15:18:56.267 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:19:01.605
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-11-23 15:19:01.605
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+E:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+E,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - JavaScript,JavaScript Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,user)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+E,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,user)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+E,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.rename.command,Rename,
        Rename the selected text.,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.ui.refactor.internal.ArtifactRefactoringCommandHandler,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,user)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as **MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts** goes:

This is a notified Eclipse bug, which appears to be still with us. Not sure what the jface has to do with it really.
Apparently **re-starting solves the problem**.

As for **java.lang.NullPointerException**
That could be absolutely anything to do with your own particular **SDK**.

If it's Android then it is most likely the irritating fact that when you attempt to run/debug a project, the entry which names the **project that you are running sets itself to blank** every now and then!

*Look in the project run/debug specifications.*